# Relationship mapping and Entitiy generator issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I came across a situation where entity generator task does not properly create "add" functions for related entities when one entity is in relation with other one twice. I am wondering if this may be caused by me not properly defining the relationship or this is a bug? If it's just a generator issue, then it's not a big deal, but if this has an unintended effect on relationship then it's a big issue and I need your advice to determine what is happening.

In a nutshell, User has oneToMany relationship with Message twice. Message entity has sender and receiver, both are related User objects. In turn User has sentmessages and receivedmessages in it's relationship. sentmessages and receivedmessages setters on User side are not generated properly.

Here's what my yml looks like, pretty simple:

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
  oneToMany:
    sentmessages:
      targetEntity: Message
      mappedBy: user
    receivedmessages:
      targetEntity: Message
      mappedBy: user


Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Message:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    body:
      type: string
    created_at:
      type: datetime
  manyToOne:
    sender:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy: sentmessages
      joinColumn:
        name: sender_id
        referencedColumnName: id
    receiver:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy: receivedmessages
      joinColumn:
        name: receiver_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

As you can see User has two relations to Message. When I generated Entities via Entity generator task it created only one function to add Messages to user and it was an incorrect one:

```
/**
 * Add sentmessages
 *
 * @param Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Message $sentmessages
 */
public function addMessage(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Message $sentmessages)
{
    $this->sentmessages[] = $sentmessages;
}
```

Instead it should have generated two add Functions like so:

```
/**
 * Add sentmessages
 *
 * @param Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Message $sentmessages
 */
public function addSentmessage(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Message $sentmessages)
{
    $this->sentmessages[] = $sentmessages;
}

/**
 * Add receivedmessages
 *
 * @param Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Message $receivedmessages
 */
public function addReceivedmessage(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Message $receivedmessages)
{
    $this->receivedmessages[] = $receivedmessages;
}
```